# getting a Could not load file or assembly Facebook with mvc3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I want develop a small MVC3 application for uploading the images into facebook for this I have download the FacebookC#SDK and I add the .dll Files into my application and I develop the code for getting only Names and email from facebook,When I run the application it through the error like this

```
  Could not load file or assembly 'Facebook, Version=5.0.50.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de' or one of its dependencies.
  The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly 
  reference. (Exception from HRESULT:   0x80131040)
```

Here is my code what I did for getting usernames

```
    public void CreateAlbum()
    {
        var client = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic me = client.Get("me");
        string firstName = me.first_name;
        string lastName = me.last_name;
        string email = me.email;
     }
```

Please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check you Bin directory, do you see Facebook SDK assembly there? If no,

1. Check is it referenced in you app? (it should be if you can complile);
2. Check that 'Copy local' property of reference is set to True;
3. All dependencies that Facebook SDK has, have to be in Bin as well. Check application - http://checkasm.booring.net/

Comment: Hi it is working for me.But i have one more issue that when i try to create album in my code it askingthe Token number.From where i can pass this token please help me...

Comment: Ok...I have solve my problem and thank you very much to give valuable suggestion to me..

Answer (score 0):

Have you added an assembly reference to your `web.config`?

```
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
           <add assembly="Facebook, Version=5.0.50.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de"/>
        </assemblies>
   </compilation>
```

Comment: Hi ..I have added assembly in web.config and i run application it showing same error...

Comment: All I can suggest is try to delete the reference and add it again. I've had some problems in the passed that have been solved by doing this, although it doesn't make any sense!

Comment: `passed` should obviously be spelled `past` - need more coffee!

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the references and the Bin folder and the error still occurs than:

1. Check which assembly .NET framework version your project is and which is the "Facebook.dll". There can be a mismatch (e.g. you will have a problem trying to run .NET 4.5 assemblies in a project that targets .NET 4.0).
2. Make sure none of your assemblies already use a namespace "Facebook" (for example the name of your project).